# How to track the completion of the program process in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need to write a program that will do something after the program process is completed, such as a calculator. That is, I work with the calculator, and then I turned it off, respectively, its process is completed and my program does the actions I set. How do I do this? How do I track process completion? I googled and found tips that you need to create a separate process through the CreateProcess function , and then use WaitForSingleObject or GetExitCodeProcess, but this is not what I need, because I don't need to create a process it is already running, or I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What "process" is "completed" and what is the "something" that your program should do? Is the "process" something you can adapt?

Comment: _The_ process or _a_ process? Your own program or someone else's program?

Comment: As a starting point, take a look at Microsoft's example: [Enumerating all processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes)

Comment: first part sounds like you want something along the line of `int main () { do_something(); do_more_when_something_is_finished();}`. Second part rather sounds like you want something like a progress bar. Please clarify the question

Comment: my main goal is for the program to be able to track that the process I specified in my program has completed. It doesn't matter what process, game, Notepad or calculator. I don't create this process, the user starts it. I need my program to understand when a user-defined process, such as a calculator, has finished. I have code that tracks processes. I need the program to understand that the process that the user started has ended and then the necessary actions are taken, such as replacing files or exiting the program
for example:
if(process_close(Calc.exe))
//doSomethingForExample
exit(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WMI to Monitor` the Process Instance. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-) is the complete steps that how to receive Event Notifications Through WMI.

And here is a code snippet that track the operation of notepad, you can refer to it:

```
#define CREATE 1
#define DELETE 0

using namespace std;

typedef function<void(void)> TNotificationFunc;
IWbemObjectSink* RegisterProcessCallback(IWbemServices* pSvc, TNotificationFunc callback, LPCWSTR ProcessName, BOOL flag);


class EventSink : public IWbemObjectSink {

    friend IWbemObjectSink* RegisterProcessCallback(IWbemServices* pSvc, TNotificationFunc callback, LPCWSTR ProcessName, BOOL flag);
    CComPtr<IWbemServices> pSvc;
    CComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> pStubSink;
    LONG m_IRef;
    TNotificationFunc m_callback;

public:
    EventSink(TNotificationFunc callback) :m_IRef(0), m_callback(callback) {}
    ~EventSink() {
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_IRef);
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() {
        LONG IRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_IRef);
        if (IRef == 0)
            delete this;
        return IRef;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv) {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IWbemObjectSink) {
            *ppv = (IWbemObjectSink*)this;
            AddRef();
            return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
        }
        else return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Indicate(
        LONG lObjectCount,
        IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR* __RPC_FAR* apObjArray
    ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
        {
            m_callback();
            _variant_t vtProp;
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(_bstr_t(L"TargetInstance"), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            if (!FAILED(hr))
            {
                IUnknown* str = vtProp;
                hr = str->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemClassObject, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&apObjArray[i]));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    _variant_t cn;
                    hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"Handle", 0, &cn, NULL, NULL);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        if ((cn.vt == VT_NULL) || (cn.vt == VT_EMPTY))
                            wcout << "ProcessId : " << ((cn.vt == VT_NULL) ? "NULL" : "EMPTY") << endl;
                        else
                            wcout << "ProcessId : " << cn.bstrVal << endl;
                    }
                    VariantClear(&cn);
                }
            }
            VariantClear(&vtProp);
        }
        return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
    }
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetStatus(LONG IFlags, HRESULT hResult, BSTR strParam, IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR* pObjParam) {
        return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
    }
};
void connect2WMI(IWbemServices** pSvc)
{
    HRESULT hres;
    CComPtr<IWbemLocator> pLoc;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        throw std::exception("CreationEvent initialization failed");
    }
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, pSvc);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        throw std::exception("CreationEvent initialization failed");
    }
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(*pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        cout << "Coult not set proxy blanket, Error code =0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        throw std::exception("CreationEvent initialization failed");
    }
}
IWbemObjectSink* RegisterProcessCallback(IWbemServices* pSvc, TNotificationFunc callback, LPCWSTR ProcessName, BOOL flag) {
    HRESULT hres;
    CComPtr<EventSink> pSink(new EventSink(callback));
    CComPtr<IUnsecuredApartment> pUnsecApp;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UnsecuredApartment, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IUnsecuredApartment, (void**)&pUnsecApp);
    CComPtr<IUnknown> pStubUnk;
    pUnsecApp->CreateObjectStub(pSink, &pStubUnk);
    IWbemObjectSink* pStubSink = NULL;
    pStubUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemObjectSink, (void**)&pStubSink);


    wstring buffer = L"SELECT * FROM ";
    if (flag == CREATE)
        buffer += L"__InstanceCreationEvent";
    else if (flag == DELETE)
        buffer += L"__InstanceDeletionEvent";
    buffer = buffer + L" WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + ProcessName + L"'";
    hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(_bstr_t(L"WQL"), _bstr_t(buffer.c_str()), WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, NULL, pStubSink);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        cout << "ExecNotificationQueryAsync failed with = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        throw std::exception("CreationEvent initialization failed");
    }
    return pStubSink;
}

void CreateEventCallBack() { cout << "Create " << endl; /*connect()*/ }
void DeleteEventCallBack() { cout << "Delete " << endl; /*disconnect()*/ }

int main() {
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;
    connect2WMI(&pSvc);
    IWbemObjectSink* CreateSink = RegisterProcessCallback(pSvc, CreateEventCallBack, L"notepad.exe", CREATE);
    IWbemObjectSink* DeleleSink = RegisterProcessCallback(pSvc, DeleteEventCallBack, L"notepad.exe", DELETE);

    getchar();
    cout << "Exit " << endl;
    pSvc->CancelAsyncCall(CreateSink);
    pSvc->CancelAsyncCall(DeleleSink);
    CreateSink->Release();
    DeleleSink->Release();
    pSvc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

It works perfectly for me:

[image]

Comment: @S1NGer-iwni- Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This method seems not to be smart,
Any way, You create process with CreateProcess, then you get process id and process name.
Next, you monitor all process list and catch the moment when id is disappeard.

```
DWORD hRetHandle = 0;
HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hSnapshot)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32W pe = { 0 };
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    if (Process32FirstW(hSnapshot, &pe))
    {
        do {
            if (wcsstr(pe.szExeFile, pswProcName))
            {
                hRetHandle = pe.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        }while(Process32NextW(hSnapshot, &pe));
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
}
return hRetHandle;
```

Comment: what you suggested is very cool, but it doesn't suit me for one reason, the process is already running I don't need to create it, that is, I have a calculator process Calc.exe which the user started when he wanted and my program should track when the process ends and for example exit the program or do something else-this is not important, it is important to track programmatically when the process ends

Comment: If calc.exe is already running, you can monitor it with process name, "caculator.exe".

Comment: Like any solution based on sampling it fails to provide the second part to make this robust: When do you sample the process list? Obviously, this doesn't have an answer. Thus a solution based on sampling cannot be made robust.